# pandas read_csv issue with reading large files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a project and created a csv while containing 13347 rows and 2500 columns but during reading the file through pandas only initial 6600 values are being read due to which my model is not building correctly. Kindly tell me why it is happening and how can I resolve it. I'm attaching a part of code with output.

```
**Code:**
data=pd.read_csv("train_foo.csv",low_memory=False)
dataset=np.array(data)
print(dataset.shape)
np.random.shuffle(dataset)
x=dataset
y=dataset
x=x[:,1:2501]
y=y[:,0]
**#splitting the data into training and testing set, normalizing the values**
x_train=x[0:12000,:]    # 12000 samples in training set
x_train=x_train/255.     # coverting the pixel values0-255 into 0-1
x_test=x[12001:13345,:] # 1345 samples in testing set
x_test=x_test/255.
y=y.reshape(y.shape[0],1)
y_train=y[0:12000,:]
y_train=y_train.T
y_test=y[12001:13345,:]
y_test=y_test.T
print("no. of training examples:"+str(x_train.shape[0]))
print("no. of test examples:"+str(x_test.shape[0]))
print("x_train shape:"+ str(x_train.shape))
print("x_test shape:"+ str(x_test.shape))
print("y_train shape:"+str(y_train.shape))
print("y_test shape: "+str(y_test.shape))

**output:**
no. of training examples:6672
no. of test examples:0
x_train shape:(6672, 2500)
x_test shape:(0, 2500)
y_train shape:(1, 6672)
y_test shape: (1, 0)
```

Comment: I ran the above code segment on my system and it ran fine. Please check if the variables aren't modified in some other part of code in your case.

Comment: Ya code is not showing any error it is resding only inital 6675 rows of csv file and rest rows are not read

Comment: In my system, the row count goes up to 12000. Try running this code segment on your system and let us know the results. I've created a similar dataframe with random data. https://codeshare.io/2WwjAv

Comment: Thanku , but I had rechecked it and there is no change of variable...I have updated pandas also but still it is not reading the csv file completely

Comment: I had even tried to read it in chunks but still not reading it completely. Can it be possible that there is a problem in csv file only

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read CSV by chunks, as given in the documentation:

```
reader = pd.read_csv('tmp.sv', sep='|', chunksize=4)
for chunk in reader:
    print(chunk)
```

Comment: I used this also but still it is reading only initial 6675 rows